# How to read the .nodes file in R

Tags: r, igraph

The file is downloaded in: networkrepository.com/fb-pages-company.php. The code below does not work. Any ideas?

```
read.nodes("fb-pages-company.nodes")
```

It would be better if the igraph object is obtained from the .nodes and .edges file.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question and tags only mention igraph, but that package does not have a function called read.nodes.  Are you using the function from the taxonomizr package?   You should include in your question a reference to whatever package you are using. Also,  you say that the code does not work.  In what way does it not work?  Does it give you an error message? What is the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the function `read.nodes` from the `taxonomizr` package,  I believe that function was not intended to be used for ingesting graphs. The `taxonomizr` documentation says:

> Functions for assigning taxonomy to NCBI accession numbers and taxon
> IDs based on NCBI's accession2taxid and taxdump files. This package
> allows the user to downloads NCBI data dumps and create a local
> database for fast and local taxonomic assignment.

I think that you are trying to ingest the fb-pages-company data as a graph. You get the full graph from just the edges file,  but you need the nodes file if you want to be able to access the names of the companies.  This answer shows how to read both files, create the graph and associate the names of the companies to the nodes. If that is not what you were trying to do, please explain what you want.

```
library(igraph)

Nodes = read.csv("fb-pages-company.nodes")
Edges = read.csv("fb-pages-company.edges")

g = graph_from_data_frame(Edges, directed = TRUE)
vcount(g)
[1] 14113
ecount(g)
[1] 52310
```

The node and edge count matches the documentation for the graph given on the source page. However,  right now,  the nodes are named by their new_id's. We want to change to the company names. We start by making it easy to refer to the company names using their new_id.

```
row.names(Nodes) = Nodes$new_id
```

Let's hang on to the new_ids in case we need them later.

```
V(g)$new_id = V(g)$name
```

Now change the names to the company names

```
V(g)$name = Nodes[V(g)$new_id, 2]
Encoding(V(g)$name) = "UTF-8"
```

The reason for specifying the encoding is that some of the names are not English, in fact, not in the latin alphabet. Without changing to UTF-8, the names would not display properly.

Now let's take a look to make sure that the result looks OK.

```
cat(paste(head(V(g)$name, 10), collapse="\n"), "\n")
Sportsnavi
NRK P1
蘋果余艾苔
99.1 WQIK
TalkTalk
Tahiti Tourisme
United
NBC OUT
Time Out Los Angeles
ConnectSafely
```

You can check this against the nodes file using the new_id's.

```
head(V(g)$new_id, 10)
 [1] "0"    "1"    "8087" "2"    "3"    "4"    "4588" "6"    "8"    "9"
```

You can search in the nodes file and find that new_id=0 corresponds with the company `Sportsnavi`.  new_id=1 corresponds with the company `NRK P1`.   And so on.

Comment: Thanks very much! Yeah, this is exactly what I want and it really helps. Sorry for not giving more details.